# Has a bout stopped during a count ever been reversed?

Tags: rules, boxing

Has there ever been a reversal of a referee's decision to stop a boxing match?

If you watch this specific bout, shown in [this](http://youtu.be/blnxDY1sdBU?t=1m56s) clip, the man knocked down isn't even allowed to come to his feet, and as soon as the ref stops the fight starts trying to tell the ref he's fine. From what we can see, his eyes look straight, and he ends up getting up looking fine. The ref didn't even make it to 6.

I get that it would be unlikely for an outside person to over-rule a match ref, but can the ref himself do it?

Comment: Watching that segment more closely, I have a couple more questions. (I don't know boxing rules, only what I see.) I have gathered that a downed boxer has until the count of five and must be up, or attempting to get up. I also thought the ref wasn't supposed to start counting until the other boxer is in the neutral corner, yet this ref is on four when he turns back and kneels. How did he get to four so quickly? I assume he called the fight because Jacob's hadn't opened his eyes or attempted to get up yet? I still want my title question answered, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That clip is very vague in terms of information regarding the physical state of fighters. I have not watched the fight but as per boxing rules, referee are in the position to decide whether the fighter is fit to continue fighting. Maybe he was getting outclassed terribly. The punch he received was a bad one, and referee can always stop a fight in order to avoid further injuries. Boxing is political, so referee can be pre meditated, there has been controversial statements made in that regard.

And yes, the referee should only start counting, after the other boxer is in neutral corner. But that rule is hardly observed in professional boxing, in an attempt to not give extra seconds to the fallen fighter. If you watch closely the ref looks to the panel, where you see a person standing up and counting. In pro boxing the counting starts as soon as the boxer touches any other part of his body other than his feet, and to answer your first question, to my knowledge no. Refereeing and judge decisions in pro boxing is pretty much ultimate and rules does'nt allow boxer to challenge them. In amateur boxing, a judge's scorecard can be reviewed and overturned if a boxer ask for it and the reversal has happened a lot of times in olympics.

Comment: watch closely..the ref looks to the panel, where you see a person standing up and counting... in pro boxing the counting starts as soon as the boxer touches any other part of his body other than his feet... and to answer your first question, to my knowledge no. Refereeing and judge decisions in pro boxing is pretty much ultimate and rules does'nt allow boxer to challenge them. In amateur boxing, a judge's scorecard can be reviewed and overturned if a boxer ask for it and the reversal has happened a lot of times in olympics.

Comment: Did that just now. Im not that good in editing :)